# Unable to make a jar file

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, devops

I am newbie with Springboot .I am unable to make jar file of Springboot with Mysql to deploy in AWS using Eclipse IDE.

I create an application which work perfectly fine in Localhost and when i want to deploy it into the AWS I comment all my application.properties file which has code like

```
#spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
#spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db_digitalprofile?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC
#spring.datasource.username=root
#spring.datasource.password=
#server.port=9090
#spring.jpa.show-sql = true
#spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

and make a new file named as application-prod.properties in src/main/resource with the code:

```
server.port=5000 
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://${RDS_HOSTNAME}:${RDS_PORT}/${RDS_DB_NAME} 
spring.datasource.username=${RDS_USERNAME}
spring.datasource.password=${RDS_PASSWORD}
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

Now when i want to make a jar file from right click on project> Run As>Maven install to create a jar file it throw a error like:

```
Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.
Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
```

I had also add following dependency in pom.xml

```
<configuration>
<finalName> digitalProfile</finalName>
</configuration>
```

Comment: It seems that your database properties such as ${RDS_HOSTNAME} are not available or can not be find. Where did you put  the values of those properties?

Comment: Can you add your ```@Configuration``` class where the ```DataSource``` bean is defined?

Answer (score 0):

**Failed to determine a suitable driver class**

You need to check the dependencies. No driver found meaning, driver jar is missing which will be used to connect to Database. mysql driver should be present in your pom file or whatever your build file is.

Answer (score 0):

Add this on your `application.properties` and it should fix your issue.

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```